# How to make Bluetooth client receive the data from the server when Activity is not running?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, android-activity

I want my `Bluetooth client` (Mobile) to receive the data from the `Bluetooth server` (pc)  when the Bluetooth activity is no more in running state.

At this time when my `Activity` is running the mobile receive the data but when I switch to the new `Activity` it create problems in receiving the data.

what I have to do for it?

Comment: you can use `Service` for getting data from server,

Comment: 'Service' or 'IntentService' I have read about service but not used it  before what I suppose to do for it?